# How can I identify start and end of uninterrupted sequences?

Tags: sql, hana

I have a list of events sorted by `TITLE` and `TIME` e.g.:

```
TITLE   |TIME
A       |11:59
A       |12:00
A       |12:01
A       |12:02
A       |12:03
B       |12:04
B       |12:05
B       |12:06
B       |12:07
B       |12:14
B       |12:15
B       |12:16
```

I want to calculate `START` and `END` of sequences. Sequence is a set of events in which minutes follow each other without gaps for same `TITLE`, e.g.:

```
TITLE   |START  |END
A       |11:59  |12:03
B       |12:04  |12:07
B       |12:14  |12:16
```

Comment: search for gaps and islands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the window functions are supported, you can do this with `lag` and a running sum to assign groups based on a 1 minute time difference.

```
select title,min(time) as start_time,max(time) as end_time 
from (select title,time,sum(col) over(partition by title order by time) as grp
      from (select title,time,
            case when lag(time) over(partition by title order by time) - time = 1 
            /*change this calculation for 1 minute time difference*/
            then 0 else 1 end as col
            from tbl
           ) t
     ) t
group by title,grp
```

Another way is

```
select title,min(time),max(time) 
from (
select title,time,
time-row_number() over(partition by title order by time) as grp
/*change this calculation to subtract row_number from time*/
from tbl
) t
group by title,grp
```

Comment: Great answer! HANA supports window functions. See https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-us/20a353327519101495dfd0a87060a0d3.html